# Defining a bean of type OAuth2AuthorizedClientService in your configuration consider. Parameter 0 of constructor in LoginController required a Bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, oauth-2.0

I encounter a
No qualifying bean of type security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
Don't understand what it expected. It's a dependancy.

Here's the LoginController :

```
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcIdToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.DefaultOAuth2User;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Map;

@RestController
public class LoginController {
private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;

public LoginController(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService) {
    this.authorizedClientService = authorizedClientService;
}

@RequestMapping("/**")
@RolesAllowed("USER")
public String getUser(){
    return "dashboard";
}

@RequestMapping("/admin")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
public String getAdmin(){
    return "Welcome, Admin";
}

@RequestMapping("/*")
public String getUserInfos(Principal activeUser){
    StringBuffer userInfos = new StringBuffer();
    if (activeUser instanceof UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken){
        userInfos.append(getUsernamePasswordPasswordLoginInfo(activeUser));
    } else if (activeUser instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken){
        userInfos.append(getOAuth2LoginInfo(activeUser));
    }
    return userInfos.toString();
}

private StringBuffer getOAuth2LoginInfo(Principal activeUser) {
    StringBuffer protectedInfo = new StringBuffer();
    OAuth2AuthenticationToken authToken = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) activeUser;
    OAuth2User principal = ((OAuth2AuthenticationToken)activeUser).getPrincipal();
    OAuth2AuthorizedClient authClient = this.authorizedClientService
            .loadAuthorizedClient(authToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), authToken.getName());
    Map<String, Object> userDetails = ((DefaultOAuth2User) authToken.getPrincipal()).getAttributes();

    String userToken = authClient.getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    protectedInfo.append("Welcome, " + userDetails.get("name") + "<br><br>");
    protectedInfo.append("email: " + userDetails.get("email") + "<br><br>");
    protectedInfo.append("Access Token: " + userToken + "<br><br>");

    OidcIdToken idToken = getIdToken(principal);
    if(idToken != null){
        protectedInfo.append("Token value: " + idToken.getTokenValue() + "<br><br>");
        protectedInfo.append("Token mapped values <br><br>");

        Map<String, Object> claims = idToken.getClaims();
        for (String key : claims.keySet()) {
            protectedInfo.append("     " + key + ":    " + claims.get(key) + "<br>");
        }
    }



    return protectedInfo;
}

private StringBuffer getUsernamePasswordPasswordLoginInfo(Principal activeUser) {
    StringBuffer usernameInfo = new StringBuffer();
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) activeUser);
    if (token.isAuthenticated()){
        User u = (User) token.getPrincipal();
        usernameInfo.append("Welcome, " + u.getUsername());
    } else {
        usernameInfo.append("NA");
    }
    return usernameInfo;
}

private OidcIdToken getIdToken(OAuth2User principal){
    if(principal instanceof DefaultOidcUser) {
        DefaultOidcUser oidcUser = (DefaultOidcUser)principal;
        return oidcUser.getIdToken();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Here's the pom.xml... maybe it's a dependancy import problem:

```
    <properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <pebble.version>3.1.5</pebble.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.pebbletemplates</groupId>
        <artifactId>pebble-spring-boot-2-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Add @Autowired configuration before `private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService;`

Comment: no.nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

Ok.
The problem was the application.properties
The openId was badly configured... it couldn't instanciate the bean... that's what written in the terminal... can't say was crystal clear but was written